# Print a part of string regex bash

Tags: regex, string, bash

From this content (in a file):

> myspecificBhost.fqdn.com myspecificaBhost.fqdn.com myspecificzBhost.fqdn.com

I need to print the next 4 characters from the "B":

> Bhost

I tried:

```
echo ${var:position1:lenght}
```

but position 1 is never equal

Comment: Is the file content supposed to be multi-line? 'Bhost' appears 3 times on the same line as currently formatted. If it does appear multiple times on a line, do you want all matches, or just the first? Do you want _any_ 4 characters following the 'B', or just letters, letters or numbers, ...?

Comment: Never equal to what? And how are `position1` and `length`, and to what values? Also, this isn't related to regular expressions at all.

Answer (score 2):

Using BASH regex:

```
s='myspecificBhost.fqdn.com myspecificaBhost.fqdn.com myspecificzBhost.fqdn.com'
[[ "$s" =~ (B[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
Bhost
```

Comment: @MortezaLSC: Thanks, You're most welcome. Your words are encouraging enough.

Comment: Your regex would be better written as `(B[[:lower:]]{4})`

Answer (score 1):

try `sed` command:

```
sed -nr '/.*c(.{4,6}).*/s//\1/p' input.txt | cut -c2-6
RESULT:
Bhost
```

With `grep` command:

```
cat input.txt | grep -o B.... | head -1
RESULT:
Bhost
```

Comment: Note you can skip the `cat` and directly use `grep -o B... input.xt`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
cat file | grep -o B....
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat` spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Bash using parameter substitution. Outputs the 4 characters
after the first 'B':

```
text='myspecificBhost.fqdn.com myspecificaBhost.fqdn.com myspecificzBhost.fqdn.com'

text=${text#*B}
text=${text:0:4}
echo "${text}"
```

Output:

```
host
```

To get the leading 'B' use

```
echo "B${text}"
```